# How to attach onClickListener of an item in custom actionBar in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an activity which contains 4 fragments. As we know the actionBar showing in fragment is of parent activity. Now I got the the custom view for every fragment and it's working fine. The problem is that when I try to access the items in custom layout of actionbar in fragment, my app crashes with a null pointer exception. This is strange because actionbar is displaying but I am unable to fetch it's widgets. I know that we can populate actionBar in fragment using menu but my requirements doesn't allow me to use it. So I have to use actionBar. I have tried different answers here most of them tells you how to set title in the fragment. Here is my code.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.user_profile_page, null);

    context = getActivity();
    commonUserProfile = new CommonClass(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.test);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    assert mActionBar != null;
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    userProfileSettings = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.follow);
    userProfileSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //null pointer on this line
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            userSettingsPage();
        }
    });

return v;
}
```

And below is the logcat:

```
12-18 07:01:14.734  31949-31949/com.example.rekky E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rekky, PID: 31949
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.rekky.Fragments.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:90)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: here there is no `R.id.follow` in your fragment view.

Comment: @NigamPatro yes it is present in the actionbar layout. can you tell me how to access it

Comment: Mean, you added custom view to the action bar?

Comment: yes I did and it's displaying perfectly but the problem is with setting the clickListeners to the widgets in the layout

Comment: can you just post setting custom view in actionBar part.

Comment: @NigamPatro I already have posted it:
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.test);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

if you get HomeActivity actionbar you can right the name of activity intead of AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your this part code

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.test);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    assert mActionBar != null;
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    //Here you are getting null pointer exception because v is not the custom layout which 
    //layout you are setting in the actionbar. So, its unable to find the ImageView inside that.


    userProfileSettings = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.follow);
    userProfileSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            userSettingsPage();
        }
    });
```

to the following

```
View actionBarView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.test, null);

android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
assert mActionBar != null;
mActionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
userProfileSettings = (ImageView) actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.follow);
userProfileSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
               userSettingsPage();
            }
});
```

Please let me know for issues.

Comment: Man that's great working fine. Please can you explain or edit the answer and add some explanation. :)

Comment: @Darkie Understood what was the mistake you did?

Comment: Yeah @nigam got it... just a silly mistake :) thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this:

```
userProfileSettings = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.follow);
```

with this:

```
userProfileSettings = (ImageView) mActionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.follow);
```

Comment: let me try this one also. ;)

Comment: nope this solution is wrong it gives "cannot resolve method" on findViewById.

Comment: I fixed the answer with: 
mActionBar.getCustomView().findViewById()

Comment: Javi Chaques that's working but nigam patro raced to got the accepted answer :) but also +1 for you :)